# SharePoint PnP PowerShell - Get choices from a Choice field

Tags: powershell, sharepoint

I am attempting to get the choice selected from a choice field but the choice fields are not returned as text.

The title field is a choice field:

```
Id    Title              GUID
--    -----              ----
76    76_                0452370b-7278-43ab-915a-e29aa6a815f7
```

What I am expecting is one of the following:

- Open
- Sold
- Shipped
- Lost

Here is the relevant code:

```
foreach ($subsite in $sites) {
    # Get the web object of the subsite
    $subWeb = Get-PnPWeb -Identity $subsite.Id
    $ctx.load($subWeb.Lists)    
    $projectStatus = Get-PnPList -Identity "Lists/Project Status" -Web $subWeb
    Invoke-PnPQuery    
    if ($projectStatus) {
        Write-Host "$($subsite.Title): $($projectStatus.Id)"
        $listItems = Get-PnpListItem -List $projectStatus.Id -Web $subWeb
        foreach ($item in $listItems) {            
            $item
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: No idea myself; just thinking it might be more fitting on https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com as it's more of a "how does SharePoint work?" kind of question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to add `().FieldValues` to the `$listItems` section:

```
$listItems = (Get-PnpListItem -List $projectStatus.Id -Web $subWeb).FieldValues
```